# Show that if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets such that $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |C|$, then $|A| \leq |C|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $|A|\leq|B|$, then $A \subset B$ and there exists $x \in B$, $x \not\in A$.

If $|B|\leq|C|$, then $B \subset C$ and there exists $x \in C$, $x \not\in B$.

Therefore there exists $x \in C$, $x \not\in A$. So, $A \subset C$ and $|A|\leq|C|$.

Would this be a correct presentation to satisfy the question?

Comment: Error: $|A|\leq|B| \implies A\subset B$.

Comment: As long as the sets are finite, this is simply transitivity of $\leq$ in the natural numbers. If the sets are infinite, you should specify what you mean by "$|A|\leq |B|$".

Comment: Also, even if it is given that $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, you can't say that there exists $x\in B$, $x\not\in A$ from $|A|\leq |B|$, since $|A|\leq |A|$, but there is no $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\not\in A$.

Comment: What the questions asks is the all info given.

Comment: $|A| \leq |B|$ should mean that there is an injection from $A$ into $B$, and then if that is the case, all you do is compose the two injections.

Comment: In any case, you should read the text again for the definitions of the symbols $|A|$ and $\leq$ in this context (is it the case that $|A|\leq |B|\iff$ there exists an injection $A\to B$? Are the sets you're considering all finite? What does $|A|$ mean if $A$ is infinite?) and make sure you understand what they say. When in doubt, turn to the definitions.

Comment: I copied the question straight from the text.  Show that if A, B, and C are sets such that the cardinality of A is less than or equal to the cardinality of B and the cardinality of B is less than or equal to the cardinality of C, then the cardinality of A is less than or equal to the cardinality of C.  That is my translation of what the question is asking. Am I correct?

Comment: @Stahl I agree, but also I'm not sure why it matters if $A$ is infinite or not.  This is  most likely an exercise from a beginning proof class and so I'm sure choice is assumed (and so checking that sets have cardinalities is beyond the scope of this problem).

Comment: This is an intro to proofs from the my discrete maths class. last class we did mathematical induction... 2^a ≤ 2^b and 2^b ≤ 2^c,then 2^a ≤ 2^c. How about this?

Comment: @RyanSullivant Probably, but the OP does not seem to understand what the symbols mean. I'm simply asking some questions that he might want to ask himself while reading the chapter (not just the exercise).

Comment: Yes, that is true, but that's not what $|A|$ means.  You are talking about the powerset.

Comment: @Stahl Ok, yes I agree with you on that.

Comment: |A| means the cardinality of Set A.

Comment: @Juan If $|A| \leq |B|$ is defined to mean that $A \subseteq B$ then also this is trivial since the subset relation is transitive. Also, yes you are right about the cardinalities, but then your proof in the question is wrong.  People are asking what you mean by $|A|$.

Comment: Yea, i messed up at first. Would the answer: 2^A ≤ 2^B and 2^B ≤ 2^C,then 2^A ≤ 2^C be conclusive?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Let me write up an answer that I "think" it should be.

Comment: Juan what I mean is that if $A$ is a finite set, say $|A| = n$ then $| \mathcal P(A)| = 2^n$. Remember, the powerset is the set of all subsets so for example, the powerset of $\{1 ,2\}$ is $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$ (notice 4 elements) and the powerset of $\{1,2,3\}$ has 8 elements.

Comment: oh thats right. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first, let's say that $|A| \leq |B|$ iff there is an injection $f : A \to B$.  (So it could be the case that $A \subseteq B$ but in general that is not true).  Now, we can prove the proposition quite simply.

Since $|A| \leq |B|$ that means there is a injection $f: A \to B$ and since $|B| \leq |C|$ that means there is an injection $g : B \to C$.  So now, to prove that $|A| \leq |C|$ what do we need?  We need an injection $h: A \to C$.  But what if we try composing the functions in this order $g \circ f$ (to remember what to do first read $\circ$ as *"after"*, so we first do $f$ then $g$).  This will give us a function with domain the same as $f$ (notice the domain of $f$ is $A$) and with codomain the same as $g$ (notice the codomain of $g$ is C).  So let $h = g \circ f$, and then $h :A \to C$.  Now all that is left to prove is that the composition of injections is indeed an injection, but this is a good exercise so I will let you try it!  If you get stuck see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497086/how-to-prove-a-bijective-function/497150#497150) (but try it first!)

Answer (score 1):

No, if $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. We have $|A|\le |B|$ but it no means that $A \subset B$.

Comment: 2^a ≤ 2^b  and 2^b ≤ 2^c,then 2^a ≤ 2^c.  How about this?

Comment: what do you mean with $2^a$? exponentiation? what are $a$ and $b$?